# Find the sum of two histograms and plot it

Tags: matlab

Good day! I have two histograms and I can draw them overlaid on top of one another. But I need to find the sums in each of the columns and plot the summed histogram.
I cannot sum them up because the histogram is built using a function, and you cannot get the values in the column from it.

```
N = 50; % Total amount
x1 = randn(N,1); % Normally distributed numbers
x2 = rand(N,1)*2; % Normally distributed numbers and shifted
k = -5:0.5:5;
R1 = histogram(x1, k)
hold on
histogram(x2, k)
grid on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need `[x1,x2]` for histogram, e.g.,

```
histogram([x1,x2],k)
```

[image]

---

If you have many variables like `x1`,`x2`, ..., `xN`, you can try

```
histogram(eval(sprintf("[%s]",strjoin(who("x*"),","))),k)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can you ask them not separated by commas, but from the first to the last?
It's just that I actually have more implementations and no way to list them manually. For example, for 4, how to do it?
x1 = randn(N,1); 
x2 = rand(N,1)*2; 
x3 = rand(N,1)*3;
x4 = rand(N,1)*4;